# Regex Multiple Capture Groups of Same Pattern inside a match

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

im new to regex, but i have a question i could not find a answer to.
i have a file that looks like this

```
more text
static abc_p ABC_P[] = {

  /* Netz I */
  {
    N1 
    N1 
    N1 
    0, 
    {
      Flg1
      0,
      Flg2
      0,
      Flg3
      0,
      Flg4
      0,
    },
  },

  /* Netz E1 */
  {
    N2 
    N2 
    N2 
    0, 
    {
      Flg1
      0,
      Flg2
      0,
      Flg3
      0,
      Flg4
      0,
    },
  },
};

more text
```

now i want only this pattern to parse it to a class same for N2 and many more text that have the same pattern

```
    N1 
    N1 
    N1 
    0, 
    {
      Flg1
      0,
      Flg2
      0,
      Flg3
      0,
      Flg4
      0,
```

now i have this pattern `static\s+abc_p\s+ABC_P\[\s*\]\s*=\s*\{(\n((?:[^{]*\{\n([^}]*)\}\,\n\s*\}\,\n)))[^;]*` build with regex101 but i does only match the first group then i read somthing about the lazy operator but when i add a `+` at the end of the las `)`it matches only the last appearance and with `+?` it matches only the first appearance is there a way i can modifiy the pattern that i get every appearance of this structure `N1` to `0,` or should i just delete the first group after i found it and then look for the next group bassicly i found `N1` delete it search for next found `N2` delete it, search for the next till i reach `;`, i want a pattern that gives me `N1` into a capture group and same for `N2` and `NX`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0J0EP5/1)

Edit :
One solution is to match only the nested arrays is to divide into to seperate matches
first to match the array

```
static\s+abc_p\s+ABC_P\[\]\s*=[^;]+;
```

and then match the nested arrays and then iterate through the nested array matches

```
\{(\s*[^}]+)
```

Comment: "Normal" regex can't handle nested structures at all. Some of the extended dialect can handle it in a very complicated way, and not all kinds of nested structures. Not to mention that a regex able to parse that input will be so complicated as to make it unmaintainable (just look at your own). What happens if the input changes just a little bit? That means remaking the regex basically from scratch. For almost all but the most simplest use-cases, I really recommend against them.

Comment: *"or should i just delete the first group after i found it and then look for the next group"* You might use `std::regex_search` to iterate, no need to modify input.